# spring boot XSRF-TOKEN how add ssl (https) , configuration

Tags: java, spring, ssl, spring-boot, spring-security

I have big problem with configure spring boot. In my application, i use XSRF-TOKEN to authorization.

```
         http.httpBasic().and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/index_orange.html",
                        "/index.html",
                        "/databases.html",
                        "/crm.html",
                        "/price.html",
                        "/var/www/download"
                )
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .requiresChannel()
                .csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/registerform","/newpassblue","/getPaymentNotification")
                .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
                .addFilterBefore(csrfHeaderFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class);
```

Authorization works very well, but how I can add SSL (HTTPS) ?

I read, that I must use  **.requiresChannel()** , but this connection causes compilation error.

My globalUserDetails:

```
        @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(securityDataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery(USER_BY_EMAILS)
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(AUTHORIZATION_BY_EMAILS)
                .passwordEncoder(new ShaPasswordEncoder(512));

    }
```

My properties file:

```
   server:
    port: 8083
    ssl:
      enabled: true
      key-alias: tomcat
      key-store: keystore.p12
      key-store-password: "*****"
logging:
    path: /var/log/gateway2
    level:
        org.springframework.security: INFO
security:
    sessions: ALWAYS
zuul:
    routes:
        front:
            url: http://192.168.14.73:8080/ui-web
        backend:
            url: http://192.168.14.63:8180/idbms-web
        backend2:
            url: http://192.168.14.50:8080/itdjg-mcalendar-ui
        crm:
            url: http://192.168.14.73:8080/ui-web/crm
        bazy-danych:
            url: http://192.168.14.73:8080/ui-web
spring:
     mvc:
        view:
            prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
            suffix: .jsp
```

Answer (score 0):

Add *and()* after *requiresChannel()*. However I think you will need to start your spring boot application with ssl.

Build a keystore.jks and run the application with the following arguments or add them to application.properties.

```
--server.port=443 --server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.jks --server.ssl.key-store-password=<password> --server.ssl.key-password=<password>
```